# How do you get Posts by multiple meta_keys and meta_values with the Rest API V2?

Tags: meta-query, rest-api

I'm trying to get my Posts by multiple meta_keys and meta_values. How do I accomplish this?

The URL should be looking like this:

`/posts?meta_key=Example&meta_value=Example2&meta_key=Example3&meta_value=Example4`

I tried to find a solution for this quite a while now, but couldn't find anything the most things where outdated.
I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into the rest api query and add your args from url's parameters

The code will look something like:

```
 function query_post_by_fields($args, $request) {
   $url_params = $request->get_param;
   //Modify $args with your url params
   return $args;
}  
add_filter('rest_post_query', 'query_post_by_fields', 10, 2);
```

Docs:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_query/